# search bar that search's on google from your website

Tags: javascript, html

I add an input search bar that takes the user inputted text and searches it on google but it's somehow not working. I tried debugging if the problem was from the search button by setting an alert function that gets triggered on img click and It worked fine. This means the issue is from my javascript function. The search should have worked but is not working. As a side question is there any way to open the search result on a different tab by `target_` it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
function searchGoogle() {
  document.getElementById("searchButton").href =
    (("https://www.google.com/search?q=") + (document.getElementById("searchInput").value));
}
```

```css
.form-group {
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 5%;
}

.form-group img {
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInput" placeholder="Google Search">
  <img id="searchButton" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/128/000000/search--v1.png" onclick="searchGoogle()" />
</div>
```

Comment: You are just assigning an `href` to an `<img />` onclick. What do you expect?

Comment: thanks for that nice suggestion @StackSlave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix:

```js
let searchGoogle; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput'); // why get it again?
searchGoogle = ()=>{
  location = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+searchInput.value;
}
});
```